# Nginx dead but pid file exists

Tags: html, http, nginx, server, port

Periodically on my server with Centos 7 and Plesk Nginx stop to work.

```
# service nginx status
nginx dead but pid file exists
```

On the Plesk guide there is written that the cause is a Misconfiguration in webserver's config.

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213926725-Websites-do-not-respond-on-80-port-but-respond-properly-on-7080-port

How can i prevent this problem?